# How to determine the configuration of the user's PC?

Tags: javascript, php, system-configuration

Is there a way to determine the hardware configuration of the user's PC, when he coming to a web resource? Like characteristics of processor or amount of RAM.

Can I do this with JS or PHP?

Comment: Nope. Web browsers don't expose that information. You could maybe do it with a Java applet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with plain JavaScript or PHP. The browser simply does not expose that information. You could write a Java applet though and retrieve what you need trough that.

Comment: That will give you your server's information, not the clients.